# What are the differences among Graphics, Raster, Image, List(ImageData) in Mathematica in terms of Head?

Tags: graphics, image

I do not know the exact conceptions of `Graphics,Raster,Image,List`(`ImageData`).

I have only dealt with and used them in *Mathematica*.

But still, I am very confused about their exact conceptions and how they work in *Mathematica* and what the differences between them are.
I would like to get your answers about that.

Thank you so much, for your help. :)

Comment: `Raster[]` is a `Graphics[]` primitive, meant to be used within `Graphics[]`. `Image[]` stands on its own.

Comment: @J.M. Good explanation but `Rasterize`?:)

Comment: @yode `Rasterize` returns a `Graphics` object containing the rasterized form of its input. It seems to me that this behavior fits well with J.M.'s comment.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for the kind answer. :) But, what is the difference between `Raster` and `Rasterize` in terms of the type of data or head?